# Bootstrap - btn-group, data-toggle="buttons" : how to select a button with JS and deselect all others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi, I'm using Bootstrap's .btn-group class like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" id="radio-popup-style-1" checked>button-1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" id="radio-popup-style-2">button-2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" id="radio-popup-style-3">button-3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" id="radio-popup-style-4">button-4
    </label>
```

In my app I need to "manually" select a button with JS and currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$('#radio-popup-style-rect-1').parent().addClass('active');
$('#radio-popup-style-rect-1').get(0).checked = true;

$('#radio-popup-style-rect-2').removeAttr('checked').parent().removeClass('active');
$('#radio-popup-style-rect-3').removeAttr('checked').parent().removeClass('active');
$('#radio-popup-style-rect-4').removeAttr('checked').parent().removeClass('active');
```

... times four, for each case that I need to select one of the buttons. That's not such a big deal if I have just 4 buttons, but now I need to have 13. Which means a lot of code.

My questions - does Bootstrap have a function that I can call to select a button and automatically deselect other buttons from the same group?

Cheers

Comment: First of all you need to change your code from using `radio` to `checkbox`.

Comment: Why would I do that? I need radio buttons not checkboxes.

Comment: Because `radio` means that you will select **only one** of them. But you need to select few values, so `checkbox`es fit better in your case.

Comment: I want only one button selected at a time, still don't get your idea.

Comment: Sorry, @nikolay-dyankov, i get your idea wrong, i've change my answer appropriately

Comment: Hold my beer ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *attribute selector*

```
$('[id*="radio-popup-style-"]').click(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true).parent().addClass('active');
    $('[id*="radio-popup-style-"]').not($(this)).removeAttr('checked').prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

#### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/6o1k1cvo/1/.

**About *regex* in *attribute selector***: http://www.thegeekyway.com/css-regex-selector-using-regular-expression-css/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **built-in** BS method to toogle button state:

(you need default button.js on your page)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L52-L66
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

```
$('#the-button-id-you-need').button('toggle');
```

Comment: I just want to point out that this solution works wonderfully, but only if you select the `label.btn`, NOT the input. You may also need to make sure that it isn't already selected before toggling it, because in some cases it can deselect an already `.active` button.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function/method. However this is unnecessary.

Use `class` attribute instead of `id`. Then the code become much simpler:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" class="radio-popup-style" checked>button-1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" class="radio-popup-style">button-2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" class="radio-popup-style">button-3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-popup-position" class="radio-popup-style">button-4
    </label>
```

JS:

```
var aEls = $('.radio-popup-style-rect');
aEls.prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('active');
aEls.eq(0).prop('checked', true).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", "label.btn", function(){$(this).find("input")[0].click();});
```